# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, datetime

Estoy intentando encontrar la media de los precios de pedidos con STATUS = 'Shipped' i que van a 'Norway' después del 01/01/2003. Para ello, cuento con el siguiente diccionario:

```
              (10158,
              {'ORDERPRICE': 1474.66,
               'ORDERDATE': '10/10/2003 0:00',
               'STATUS': 'Shipped',
               'PRODUCTLINE': 'Motorcycles',
               'PRODUCTCODE': 'S24_2000',
               'CUSTOMERNAME': 'Baane Mini Imports',
               'CITY': 'Stavern',
               'COUNTRY': 'Norway'}),
             (10159,
              {'ORDERPRICE': 5205.27,
               'ORDERDATE': '10/10/2003 0:00',
               'STATUS': 'Shipped',
               'PRODUCTLINE': 'Motorcycles',
               'PRODUCTCODE': 'S10_1678',
               'CUSTOMERNAME': 'Corporate Gift Ideas Co.',
               'CITY': 'San Francisco',
               'COUNTRY': 'USA'}),
             (10168,
              {'ORDERPRICE': 3479.76,
               'ORDERDATE': '10/28/2003 0:00',
               'STATUS': 'Shipped',
               'PRODUCTLINE': 'Motorcycles',
               'PRODUCTCODE': 'S10_1678',
               'CUSTOMERNAME': 'Technics Stores Inc.',
               'CITY': 'Burlingame',
               'COUNTRY': 'USA'}),             
             (10188,
              {'ORDERPRICE': 5512.32,
               'ORDERDATE': '11/18/2003 0:00',
               'STATUS': 'Shipped',
               'PRODUCTLINE': 'Motorcycles',
               'PRODUCTCODE': 'S10_1678',
               'CUSTOMERNAME': 'Herkku Gifts',
               'CITY': 'Bergen',
               'COUNTRY': 'Norway'}) ...... y continua.
```

El diccionario anterior está contenido en la variable `d_ordenat`. He realizado el siguiente código:

```
import numpy as np

preu_avg = np.mean([v['ORDERPRICE'] for k, v in d_ordenat.items()
                    if v['STATUS'] == 'Shipped' and
                    v['COUNTRY'] == 'Norway' and
                    v['ORDERDATE'] > datetime.date(year=2003,month=1,day=1)])
```

Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el código me dispara el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'
```

Creo que el campo ORDERDATE del diccionario es entendido como un `str` y por eso no es capaz de comparar. Cómo puedo cambiar el tipo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenass, puedes pasar de string a datetime con datetime.datetime.strptime()

En uno de los ejemplos que tienes se puede hacer como:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("11/18/2003 0:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Que daría como resultado un objeto datetime: datetime.datetime(2003, 11, 18, 0, 0)

El otro objeto a comparar también debe ser datetime y no date. Por lo que:

```
datetime.date(year=2003,month=1,day=1)
```

debe ser sustituido por:

```
datetime.datetime(year=2003,month=1,day=1)
```

Una vez teniendo los dos objetos puedes compararlos, las clase datetime tiene definida la sobrecarga de esos operadores

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("11/18/2003 0:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") > datetime.datetime(year=2003,month=1,day=1) #->True
```

En tu caso quedaría como:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(v['ORDERDATE'], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") > datetime.datetime(year=2003,month=1,day=1)]
```

Te dejo una tablita para saber como usar esa especie de regex con la libreria datetime:

```
%y    year abreviado        %j    yearday numero            %M    minute
%Y    year completo         %d    monthday numero           %S    second
_                           %a    weekday abreviado         %f    microsecond
%b    month abreviado       %A    weekday completo          
%B    month completo        %w    weekday numero            
%m    month numero                                            
_                           %H    hour de un dia            
%U    week numero           %I    hour de un medio dia      
_                           %p    am/pm
```

Espero haberte ayudado :)